# Gradient of 2D convolution

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, convolution, image-processing

For a image $u\in \mathbb{R}^{20\times 20}$, we have a filter $h\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$, i.e. the average blur filter is
$$
h =\frac{1}{9}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
What is the gradient of $h*u$ with respect to u?
Furthermore, we transform u into a vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^{400}$ and transform $h*u$ into another vector $\tilde{v}\in\mathbb{R}^{400}$. If $\tilde{v} = f(v)$, what is the gradient of $f(v)$?

Answer (score 0):

The [helix transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_discrete_convolution#The_Helix_Transform) will map a ${\rm 2D}$ convolution to ${\rm 1D}$.
$$\eqalign{
&H',\,U' = {\rm helix}(H,U) \\
&v = {\rm vec}(V)\\
&V = H*U &({\rm 2D\;convolution}) \\
&v = h'*u' &({\rm 1D\;convolution}) \\
}$$
In turn, ${\rm 1D}$ convolutions can be calculated as multiplication by a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix#Discrete_convolution)
$$\eqalign{
v &= h'*u'  \;=\; {\cal H'}\cdot u' \\
}$$

Finally, the scalar  [derivative of a convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Differentiation)  is
$$\eqalign{
Dv &= h'*(Du') \\
}$$
Putting all of these pieces together, you can construct the gradient in question.